# Is there any software that acts as a “routing sandbox”?

Tags: windows, routing

So that any network traffic generated by the programs launched inside this "sandbox" are routed through a specific gateway.

In case you are curious by what is the use case for this:

All network traffic from my PC goes to the internet through a connection which I trust, but I also have another connection that I don't trust but has better latency ,and for gaming it is better to use the one with best latency.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for "source" or "policy" based routing. That is, you want packets to take a specific path depending on where they are coming from. Start by "search engine-ing"  . . . windows policy based routing or windows source based routing.

There are some application based routing options with windows . . .

Good luck.

Steve J